# Sending an HTTP request while running Immutant

Tags: clojure, immutant

I'm running Immutant.  Can/should I use clj-http to send requests, or is there a better way of going about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly *can*. You haven't really provided enough info to suggest whether you *should*, but Immutant and clj-http are largely orthogonal: using one shouldn't affect whether you use the other.